# Modifying page with JavaScript removes all CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a webpage which takes an XML file from a podcast and churns out a list of all the titles and the direct links to the podcasts. For the most part this is working however when I try to add style to the page with CSS, it just disappears so the page is just as it was if there wasn't any styling applied to it in the first place.

Here is the piece of JavaScript I am using the write the list on the page.

```
var podcasts;
var titles = new Array;
var urls = new Array;

var yogpod = function() {

    document.write("<h1> YogPod </h1>");

    var xml = loadXMLDoc("http://localhost/yogpod/yogpod.xml");
    podcasts = xml.getElementsByTagName("item");

    //Extract info into arrays for ease of use
    for (i=0; i<podcasts.length; i++)   {   titles[i] = podcasts[i].children[0].textContent         }
    for (i=0; i<podcasts.length; i++)   {   urls[i] = podcasts[i].children[6].getAttribute('url')   }


    //Make podcast 1 first
    titles.reverse();
    urls.reverse();

    //Write podcasts and URLs on page
    for (i=0; i<podcasts.length; i++)
    {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        //div.setAttribute('class', 'podcast');
        div.className='podcast';
        var titleText = document.createTextNode(titles[i]);
        var urlText = document.createTextNode(urls[i]);

        div.appendChild(titleText);
        div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        div.appendChild(urlText);
        div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

        var a = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        a.appendChild(div); 
    }
}
```

And this is what the result is, along what Chrome thinks the page is.
[image: Markup]

**EDIT: I removed the** `document.write("<h1> YogPod </h1>")` **line and it fixed it. Can anyone tell me why this is?**

Comment: What does the resulting markup look like?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you might want to change `div.setAttribute('class', 'podcast');` to div.className='podcast';`

Comment: Are you sure your CSS is being loaded? From the screenshot, it looks like the style element is empty. Is there any other JavaScript?

Comment: Changing the JavaScript didn't work. There is no other JavaScript being loaded.

Comment: Do you mind creating a Fiddle? It will be easier to diagnose than us guessing what is or isn't including/loading properly.

Comment: I need another picture but this time with you clicked on divs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do a `document.write` *after* the page has loaded, it empties the document before writing the specified content. Replace the `document.write` with `document.createElement("h1")` and `document.body.appendChild(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
       // you have to create new element and new textNode


var s = document.createElement('h1');
var t = document.createTextNode('yodu..');

var headr = s.appendChild(t);
```